# MemCachedClient get is returning null after setting same key

Tags: java, client, memcached

I am using below code to set and get value from Memcached java using MemCachedClient...

```
SockIOPool sockIOPool = SockIOPool.getInstance();
sockIOPool.setServers("array of server urls");
sockIOPool.setHashingAlg(CONSISTENT_HASH);
sockIOPool.initialize();

MemCachedClient memCachedClient = new MemCachedClient();

boolean set = memCachedClient.set("id.123546", 123456);
System.out.println(set);
Object value = memCachedClient.get("id.123456");
System.out.println(value);
```

In above code set value returns true but when I get value is giving null.

I am using below maven dependency

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>com.whalin</groupId>
  <artifactId>Memcached-Java-Client</artifactId>
  <version>3.0.2</version>
</dependency>
```

What am I missing here ?
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

The keys are not the same, you have a typo:

```
memCachedClient.get("id.123456");
```

uses a different key than

```
memCachedClient.set("id.123546", 123456);
```

the *4* and *5* are swapped in *set()*.

Comment: Thanks Luciano... That was a silly mistake... Cheers.